# C# patterns subclasses

Tags: c#, design-patterns, methods, decorator

I have class `Person`, two child classes `Staff` and `Student`, interface `IPerson`. Also I have a class `Database` and class `Gateway`. Class `Database` has

```
private string id = "username";
```

and method

```
public void getID() {return id;}
```

Both Staff and Student have getID() methods. Gateway has to check if method getID() was requested by `Staff` (`return id`) or `Student` (`return "Go away!"`). 
Can anyone please help me with that. I was thinking about using `Gateway` as an interface of `Database` class, but because I am only trying to learn C#, I don't really know how to do that. Or maybe there's a better way of doing this... Please help
Thanks

here's some code:

```
public class Staff : Person
  {


    public Staff() {}
    public Staff(string id): base(id) {}
    public override string getName()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Update(object o)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(id + " notified that {1}", id, o.ToString()); 
    }
    public override void UpdateMessage(object p)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(id + " notified about new message in chat: {1}", id, p.ToString()); 
    }
  }
```

---

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public Student() {}
    public Student(string id): base(id) {}
    public override string getName()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Update(object o) 
    {
     Console.WriteLine(id +"  notified that {1}", id, o.ToString());
    }
    public override void UpdateMessage(object p) 
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Message for " + id + "  {1}", id, p.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

```
 public abstract class Person : IPerson
{
    string id;
    public Person() { }
    public abstract string getName();
    public Person(string i) { this.id = i; }
    public abstract void Update(Object o);
    public abstract void UpdateMessage(Object p);
}

public interface IPerson     
 {
   void Update(Object o);
   void UpdateMessage(Object p);
   string getName();
 }
```

---

```
 class database
 {
     public string username = "username";
     private string name =  "user details";
     private string grade = "user grade";

     public string getName(Object o)
     {
         if (o is Staff) { return name; }
         else { return "Go away!"; }
     }
     public string getgrade() { return grade; }
 }


 public class Gateway
   {
    public void DoSomethingWithPerson(IPerson person)
    {
        string iD = person.getName();
        if (person is Student)
        {
            return "go away!";
        }
        else if (person is Staff)
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add please all code here

Comment: This is a bit confusing... Could you re-write what you have and what you want? Are you passing Staff / Student into the Database class? Is it instantiating them (in which case use IoC instead)? Bit more clarity needed for an answer I think.

Comment: your `getID()` method cannot return void, you probably have to use `public string getID() {return id;}`. Also take a look at properties in .NET, for they seem better suited for what you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would discourage `is` chains altogether. It violates [Liskov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In short, this means it is hard to add a new `IPerson` implementation without modifying `Gateway` to cope with that new type. Or it forces developers to descend from one of the existing types to implement a new `IPerson`, in which case, what is the point of the interface over just the abstract `Person` type?

```
public class Gateway
{
 public string DoSomethingWithPerson(IPerson person)
 {
    return person.DoSomething();
 }
}

//then IPerson implementors like Student can provide the custom behaviour.
public class Student : Person
{
  public string DoSomething()
  { 
      return "Go Away!";
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have something similar in your Gateway class:

```
public class Gateway
{
    public void DoSomethingWithPerson(IPerson person)
    {
        string id = person.getID();
        if (person is Student)
        {
            // do stuff for student, even cast is possible (Student) person
        }
        else if (person is Staff)
        {
            // do stuff for staff, even cast is possible (Staff) person
        }
    }
}
```

The code above assumes that `getID()` returns the string id (you have `public void getID()` in the state of the question at the moment of this answer).

---

**A note on the** `is` **keyword**

The `is` keyword allows for checking at runtime the type of an object. This works for interfaces, classes and structs. If you have hierarchy and exclusive conditions, you must be careful, since the following code:

```
if (person is Person)
{
    return;
}
else if (person is Student)
{
    // do student stuff
}
```

will never "do student stuff" when you have passed a `Student` instance, since `person is Person` is true for any instance of `Student` because `Student` extends `Person`. To overcome this, use the concrete type checks **before** the more-abstract one:

```
if (person is Student)
{
    // do student stuff
}
else if (person is Person)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo. I did what you ve said but now getting error: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ConsoleApplication1.IPerson' is less accessible than method 'ConsoleApplication1.Gateway.DoSomethingWithPerson(ConsoleApplication1.IPerson)'

Comment: @Dims - this is due to the `DoSomethingWithPerson` method being `public` and the `IPerson` interface not. Generally, you cannot use classes/interfaces with lesser visibility than the signature of the methods, so I suggest to make `IPerson` public. By the time of the answer, I did not have your full code.

Comment: Ahh.... yes sorry i got that fixed.. it's different error now. actually 8 of them: Error 2 'ConsoleApplication1.Person.id' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @Dims, I do not want to appear rude, but I am sure some googling will be able to help you with resolving the compiler errors. It seems you need to read more about accessibility identifiers (`private`, `public`, `protected`) and how they work. There are a plenty of articles and books on that matter.

Comment: Well, that's what I was doing in the past four days... I just couldn't find easy explanation. You know, easy enough to understand for a beginner. That's why I decided to ask a question here..Well.. Thanks anyway..

Comment: @Dims, StackOverflow is not the right place for compiler errors, people here are more advanced and will hardly waste time on these. For beginners like you, I'd recommend taking a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com. This is a version of stack overflow for beginner programmers and most of the issues you are about to face will be addressed there. I hope I don't leave you with bad feelings, all we want to do with these sites is help each other.